# How to detect a particular group of option group has been selected with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is a very tiny problem that I got. Following is my html select tag

```
<select id="category" name="category" style="opacity: 0; ">             
                <optgroup label="Default">  
                    <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                    <option value="IT">IT</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="User Created">             
                    <option value="Categoy">Categoy</option>
                    <option value="My Category">My Category</option>
                </optgroup>
      </select>
```

I have to show a button when the user select an option which is in the User Created label optgroup. Can anyone give me a suggestion how to do it with jquery

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/27RLj/

**HTML**

```
<select id="category" name="category" style="opacity: 1; ">             
   <optgroup label="Default">  
         <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
         <option value="IT">IT</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="User Created">             
         <option value="Categoy">Categoy</option>
         <option value="My Category">My Category</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

<input type="button" value="button" id="btn"/>​
```

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").hide();


    $("#category").change(function(){
        var selected = $("option:selected", this);
        selected.parent()[0].label=="User Created"?$("#btn").show(): $("#btn").hide();     

    });

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

*HTML*

```
    <select id="category" name="category" style="opacity: 1; ">             
            <optgroup label="Default">  
                <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                <option value="IT">IT</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="User Created">             
                <option value="Categoy">Categoy</option>
                <option value="My Category">My Category</option>
            </optgroup>
  </select>
 <input id="btn" type="button" style="display:none" value="Press Me" />
```

*Script*

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
    var clicked = $(this)
                     .find('option:selected') // get selected option
                     .parent()   // get that option's optgroup
                     .attr("label");   // get optgroup's label
       if( clicked == "User Created")
       {
         $('#btn').css('display','');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#btn').css('display','none');
        }
    });
});
```

Check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NWDC8/23/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I guess Tariqulazam's script is very optimized. Anyway thanks a lot

Comment: yes, Tariqulazam's answer is good and it is not important that you accept my answer or not, important is you get your issue resolved, so, cheer up..